# Mastercard Hosted Checkout session

Tags: javascript, php, html, integration, mastercard

HOW I CAN USE session IN Mastercard Hosted Checkout

Integration:
https://banquemisr.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

MY CODE
works, but at the end of the payment process, the message appears
"Payment Unsuccessful
Your transaction was unsuccessful, please check your details and try again."
I think he needs to add sessions in order for the process to go well ..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
     <title>XXXXXX</title>    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://banquemisr.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/61/checkout.js" data-error="errorCallback" data-cancel="cancelCallback"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /* ############################# Config */

    //Type Your commission that will be added to the real amount
    let commission = 0;

    //Start amount
    let realAmount = 0;

    //currency
    let currency = "EGP";

    //Goods Item name and details
    let itemDescription = "XXXXXX";

    //Store Name
    let clietnName = document.title;//"Store Name";
    //Store address 1 & 2
    let clientAddress1 = "200 Sample St";
    let clientAddress2 = "1234 Example Townt";

    //cancel page redirect
    let cancelURL = 'https://google.com';


    //payment id    
    let idValue = '';//Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

  /* ########################### End config */
            function errorCallback(error) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
            function cancelCallback() {
                  console.log('Payment cancelled');
                  window.href = cancelURL;
            }

            Checkout.configure({
                merchant: 'XXXXXX',
                order: {
                    amount: function() {
                        //Dynamic calculation of amount
                        return realAmount + commission;
                    },
                    currency: currency,
                    description: itemDescription,
                    id: idValue,
                },
                interaction: {
                  operation : "PURCHASE",
                    merchant: {
                        name: clietnName,
                        address: {
                            line1: clientAddress1,
                            line2: clientAddress2
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            function makePayment()
            {
                realAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);
                document.getElementById('amount').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('pay').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('cancel').disabled = true;
                Checkout.showLightbox()
                return false;
            }
        </script> 
 </head> 
 <style>
    
    .card-header .icons .fa-cc-discover{
        color: #027878;
    }
    .card-header .icons .fa-cc-amex{
        color: #ef6903;
    }
    label.labelamount{
        color: #ef6903;
    }
    .card-body label{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .submitpay{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #ef6903;
        width: 83%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid #ef6903;
  border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .icons{
        text-align: right;
    }
    .inputamout{
        width: 85%;
    }
    body{
        background:  url("http://www.rimallytravel.com/wp-content/themes/altair/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;

    }
    .imgbq{
        margin: auto;
    }
    .imglogo{
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
<body class="bg-danger pt-5">
    <div class="container">
       
            <div class="row">
          
                    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-10 offset-1 pl-0 pr-0">
                        <div class="card1">
                                <img class="imglogo" src="http://www.rimallytravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ww.png" alt="logo"  >
                                <br /><br /><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>




      <div class="row">
          
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-10 offset-1 pl-0 pr-0">
              <div class="card">
                  
                    <div class="card-header">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-12 pt-2">
                              <h6 class="m-0"><strong>Payment Details</strong></h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-12 icons">
                             <img class="imgcredit" src="http://www.rimallytravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Credit-Card-Visa-And-Master-Card-PNG-File-300x65.png" alt="banq" width="170" >
                              
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <form onsubmit="return makePayment()">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label class="labelamount" for="exampleInputamount"><strong>Amount</strong></label>
                                    </br>
                                      <input class="inputamout" type="number" min="1" step="0.01" id="amount" style="text-align: center;" required> EGP
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                            <input class="submitpay" type="submit" id="pay" value="Pay Now">
         <br />
         <img class="imgbq" src="http://www.rimallytravel.com/wp-content/themes/altair/bq.png" alt="banq" width="125" >
         <br />
         <input type="hidden" id="cancel" onclick="cancelCallback()" value="Cancel"  >
                      </form>
                    </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>    
  <script>
    document.getElementById('amount').value = realAmount;
</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From a quick look over api, seems that you should run that first that `curl` which will generate a ssid.(step by step as doc say). Then pass response-ssid to you js-config. Cannot see anywhere from your code where curl is invoked.

Comment: @TraianGEICU Thanx for ur help , that is curl `curl https://banquemisr.gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/61 \
-d "apiOperation=CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION" \
-d "apiPassword=$PWD" \
-d "apiUsername=merchant.<your_merchant_id>" \
-d "merchant=<your_merchant_id>" \
-d "interaction.operation=AUTHORIZE" \
-d "order.id=<unique_order_id>" \
-d "order.amount=100.00" \
-d "order.currency=USD"`
how can i use it with my code and how i call that curl

Comment: yes, they say that on response should have a ssid. But notice, when invoke you should put some amount, currency (fine but as my understand amount should come in second step, from interface ... just go deep with docs). Anyway, use their test link (should have) and see first curl_response.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Comment: could install curl on cmd and run first from there (just google it) but from php need to look over php_doc

Comment: @TraianGEICU thanx for ur help

Comment: Does this solution work with wordpress?

Comment: I need help with a similar matter.